# The use of article in "(The) originator drugs that have been approved and recommended for use are listed in Table 1"

Tags: articles

> **The** originator drugs that have been approved in Russia and are recommended for use as reference drugs are listed in Table 1.

Would the absence of **the** imply that Table 1 lists only *some* of the approved-and-recommended drugs? Would the presence of **the** imply that the table lists all such drugs, with no exceptions?

Comment: The absence of **the** there would not imply a partial list, IMO. One might infer it, but the inference is unjustified.  *Artificial colorings approved for use in foods are listed on Table 1*.  A company should not use a food coloring which is not shown on Table 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There's no clear suggestion that the list is incomplete without *the,* but it's possible that it's incomplete in some sense, and certainly "more possible" than would be the case if *the* were used.

Including *the* sends a stronger suggestion that the list is complete. (We can say this if we know nothing more about the context.)

Either way, it is not specified, but a typical reader would assume (either with or without *the*) that the list includes all approved originator drugs that the writer believes the reader would find relevant; or, that, if it is partial in some sense, this is thought by the writer to be insufficiently important to warrant greater specificity.

Including *the* tends to send a signal that the writer believes that the reader knows which originator drugs are being discussed.

The absence of *the* may be a free choice (zero article before originator drugs as a collective mass or substance, and/or originator drugs in some sort of general or imprecise sense, eg, *those approved so far at the time of writing).*

It's possible that the zero article could signify such kind of impreciseness or tentativeness, whereas *the* may more likely convey some kind of ... definiteness (!) such as *You know which* or *all (each and every).*

Comment: Thank you, Jim! Is the use of **in Table 1** okay, I wonder. I noticed that TRomano wrote **on Table 1**.

Comment: I would expect *in,* but I find *on* acceptable.

Comment: Using 'in Table 1' versus 'on Table 1' jumps out as a typo to me. [The Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=listed+in+table%2C+listed+on+table&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1950&year_end=2009&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Clisted%20in%20table%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Blisted%20in%20Table%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Blisted%20in%20table%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Clisted%20on%20table%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Blisted%20on%20Table%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Blisted%20on%20table%3B%2Cc0) seem to indicate "in" is more popular, but it looks like "on table" is used in a lot of texts about law and regulation.

Comment: @Coll That should be a specialized legal usage, as in *the motion is on table* as in *on hold, deferred.*

Comment: Here's an example *[E Mass flow rate of total organic HAP's **listed on table 8 or table 9 of this subpart** exiting the biological treatment process kilograms per hour](https://books.google.com/books?id=Uwk9AAAAIAAJ&dq=%22listed%20on%20table%22&pg=PA523#v=onepage&q=%22listed%20on%20table%22&f=false)*

Comment: @Col Yes. Neither preposition there surprises me, and I doubt I'd notice if I was reading along and encountered either in this way. *In* for being inside the area of a table (a bordered thing), *on* as being on the surface of a page or screen. I think we've laid it all out on the table. :)

Comment: @CowperKettle, I would use "in" Table 1. But this is [not the case](https://6thfloor.blogs.nytimes.com/2013/06/06/is-it-on-line-or-in-line/?_r=0) for everyone.